# Know repetitions in multiset by its sum

Tags: algorithm, set

I'm given the size `N` of the multiset and its sum `S`. The elements of the set are supposed to be continuous, for example a multiset `K` having 6 (`N=6`) elements `{1,1,2,2,2,3}`, so `S=11` (the multiset always contains first `N` repeating natural numbers).

How can I know the total changes to make so that there can be no repetitions and the set becomes continuous?

For the above example the multiset `K` needs 3 changes. Hence, finally the set `K` will become `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`.

What I did is, I found out the actual sum (i.e. `n*(n+1)/2`) and subtracted the given sum. Let it be `T`.

Then, `T=ceil(T/n)`, then the answer becomes `2*T`, it is working for most cases.

But, I guess I'm missing some cases. Does there exists some algorithm to know how many elements to change?

I'm given only the size and sum of the multiset.

Comment: Why not try to do your own homework

Comment: `{1,1,2,2,2,3}` is **not** a set. If you consider it a set then it's a *3* element set `{1,2,3}`. You probably mean *multisets*.

Comment: @Bakuriu ok....yes i meant a multiset...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already noticed, for a given `N`, the sum should be `S' = N * (N-1) / 2`. You are given some value `S`.

Clearly, if `S' = S` the answer is 0.

---

If `S'- S <= N - 1`, then the multiset that requires least changes is

```
{1, 2, ..., N-1, X}
```

where `X = N - (S' - S)`, which is in the range `[1, N-1]`. In other words, `X` makes up for the difference in sum between the required and the actual multiset. Your answer would be 1.

---

If the difference is larger than `N-1`, then also `N-1` cannot be in the multiset. If `S'- S <= (N - 1) + (N - 2)`, a multiset that requires least changes is

```
{1, 2, ..., N-2, 1, X}
```

where `X = N + (N - 1) - (S'- S)`, which is in the range `[1, N-2]`. Your answer would be 2.

---

Generalizing, you would get a table like:

```
   S' - S    |  answer
-----------------------
[   0,    0] |     0
[   1,  N-1] |     1
[   N, 2N-3] |     2
[2N-2, 3N-6] |     3
```

and so on. You could find a formula to get the answer in terms of `N` and `S`, but it seems much easier to use a simple loop. I'll leave the implementation to you.